# bootstrap link conflicting each other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am working on project and i join the project in middle, the project have bootstrap offline bootstrap.min.js file. 
Now I am doing the some changes and making new pages in my website. but when I use some thing like modal or well in my project and then bootstrap not working and when I used online bootstrap link or cdn then modal and well work. but previous work or pages get effected. why offline bootstrap not working in my webpage.

This is my offline bootstrap file

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/styles/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

and this my online link.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

how to avoid conflict between this link. or tell the  better way to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

Offline version always works for me. But make sure you check whether you've included popper.js or not! The rule here is you have to use only one version either cdn or offline version. 
For me whenever i have used offline version i removed `integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"` this from my link and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Setup an environment variable, such as `ENV`. Then on your development machine set that to 'development'. Then prior to loading that styles, do

```
<?php if (getenv('ENV') && getenv('ENV') === 'development') {
echo '<link href="' . base_url() . 'assets/styles/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >';
} else {
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">';
}
?>
```

What this does is, checks to see if the environment variable by the name 'ENV' is set, and if so, then checks if it equals 'development'. Then it loads the local, otherwise the CDN. You won't need to make any changes on your production machine, just on your local, you need to set an environment variable.